# NPM can't install Gulp - ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, econnreset

I'm trying to install Gulp for months, literally. Since August or earlier. Every effing time, It gets stuck for a minute, and then, throws ECONNRESET error.

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. 
Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/glob-stream/-/glob-stream-3.1.18.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chilli\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-22T17_48_46_679Z-debug.log
```

I have no proxy, I've been searching google for months, and nothing has worked. I updated both nodejs and npm multiple times, cleared cache or proxy settings, changed repository for http version... Log says it can't install glob-stream package, I can't install it manually too - the same error...

NPM log: https://pastebin.com/Ci0AYYzY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you don't install `gulp` package globally but `gulp-cli`. Your log says, you tried to install the `gulp` package, which you want to install just as dev dependency(`-D` argument).

Try this:

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
cd your/project/dir
npm install gulp -D
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, but wow - that worked somehow! Thank you :)